# Move file with a dash

Tags: command-line, mv

I move file using Midnight Commander to file with name "-name.csv". But 'mc' thinks I use option. Why is this happening? And how I can move to file with name like "-name.csv".

```
desktop:~/s$ mv name.csv "-name.csv"
mv: invalid option -- 'a'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not `mc`, it's `mv`. Quoting doesn't help because the quotes are interpreted by the shell so `mv` receives unquoted parameters `name.csv` and `-name.csv`. You need to hide the dash so that option parser in `mv` stops thinking it's an option. Use relative path `./` for the current directory, or full path:

```
mv name.csv ./-name.csv
mv name.csv "`pwd`"/-name.csv
```

Comment: The sinopsis says the parameter must be in front. 'mv [OPTION]... [-T] SOURCE DEST' Afrer that follows 'source' and 'directory'/'dest'. How 'mv' see parameter?

Comment: Very much depends on the option parser. Most option parsers allow to intermix flags, options and arguments almost freely.